# magento 2 PHPSESSID cookie not show on browser

Tags: cookie

I am working on one project, which is built in Magneto as the backend (graphql) and in NextJS as the frontend.Both are on different domains actually,issue is that the PHPSESSID cookie not generated on the browser.